# Приватные поля в классе

Tags: kotlin, getter, setter

Изучаю сейчас котлин и запуталась с модификаторами доступа. В Java поля класса обычно приватные, а для доступа пишутся `getter` и `setter`. Например:

```
public class People{
   private String name;

   public String getName(){
    return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Но если его конвертировать в Kotlin то получается:

```
class People {
    var name: String? = null
}
```

Судя по документации, если нет модификатора доступа, то это по умолчанию `public`, то есть нарушается инкапсуляция.
Так ли это? И как все же сделать приватное поле и `getter` и `setter`?

Comment: Это эквивалентный код, просто Kotlin снимает с вас необходимость вручную описывать геттеры и сеттеры (но на самом деле они создадутся автоматически). Если вы попробуете объект котлиновского класса из Java создать, то обращение к полю name будет возможно только через геттер и сеттер, но не напрямую.

Comment: в котлине нет полей, есть свойства, они с геттерами и сеттерами (var), которые вы можете переопределять

Comment: Если мы говорим о Котлине для JVM, то под капотом будут все те же геттеры и сеттеры на приватным полем. Только внешне Котлин вас избавляет от лишней писанины, изображая свойство.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример на Котлине

```
class People {
    var name: String? = null
}
```

Генерирует вот такой JVM байткод (оставил только сигнатуры)

```
public final class People {
  private Ljava/lang/String; name
  public final getName()Ljava/lang/String;
  public final setName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  public <init>()V
}
```